# JQuery - passing variable to php script

Tags: php, jquery

im stucked with following issue. I have an javascript (jquery) function where i need to pass a variable to php ON .success method. See below Please:

http://paste.org/55404

Any idea how to achieve this? Or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery runs in the browser. PHP runs on the server. So you can not mix and match them like that.

Instead, you will have to use AJAX or another mechanism to contact the server and get the information you need.

Depending on your use case, there may be other solutions, such as inserting the values into the page when the server generates it, or putting the values in a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is it possible to send me some nice links where can i read/see some examples of using AJAX in such a situations? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your [code](http://paste.org/55404), The .success method is called, when your ajax request to "index.php" returns a successful response.

Since you need to get the PHP variable in this function, you can attach the value of "genNavSide()" to the response as a parameter. It is the same way you assigned pageName value, and content value to the response data.

For example, instead of :

```
  <?php echo pagesSideBar('data.pageName') ?>
```

call the function from your index.php, during the ajax call.

```
   $sidebar = pagesSideBar($PageName);
   $response->sidebar = $sidebar; // I just mentioned object, you can assign whatever way you are following to create the response
```

In the .success method :

```
     jQuery('#links').html(data.sidebar);
```

Comment: Well im not sure if i correctly understood. What i need is following:

jQuery('<?php echo genNavSide(HERE_I_WANT_TO_PASS_VARIABLE); ?>').removeClass('active');

and

jQuery('#links').html('<?php echo pagesSideBar(HERE_I_WANT_TO_PASS_VARIABLE); ?>');

But passing it like 'data.pageName' doesnt work.

Comment: Basically this does not work:
jQuery('#links').html('<?php echo pagesSideBar('data.pageName'); ?>');

Comment: Excellent. Thanks a lot. Works perfect.  :-)

But now i have another issue with following onClick method to pass again the variable to php. I can not see the same fix as mentioned above:

   jQuery('<php echo method(HERE_I_WANT_TO_PASS_VARIABLE_OF_ACTUAL_PAGE_SELECTED) ?>').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var pageName = jQuery(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];

      requestSide(pageName);
   });

Basically i wanna passs the var pageName = jQuery(this).attr('href').split("#")[1];
into the php variable. 
Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mixing things up. That has to be a jquery selector to attach on click. Or, add a similar ajax call before, and get that return value of the method and attach to on click.